# nio Datagram read block in android api 10

Tags: nio, android-2.3-gingerbread

This code works fine on donut (api 4) and Jelly beans ( api 17), but it stucks on GINGERBREAD (api 10), when it comes to  sock.read(bb);

No exceptions are thrown. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
(new Thread(new Runnable() {  @Override public void run() {
    try {


                DatagramChannel sock= DatagramChannel.open();
                sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1910));
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
                sock.configureBlocking(false);  
                                pr("SOCKET Read start!!!");
                sock.read(bb);
                pr("SOCKET Read passed!!!");



    } catch (IOException e) {
                pr("SOCKET BAD!!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}})).start();
```

Comment: Looks like you have yet another Android NIO bug. That shouldn't block.

Comment: But it does. Can anybody check this, or explain? I've tested it on emulator and real device with android 2.3.3

Comment: The explanation is a bug. Report it.